# How to do realtime subdomain updates for users?

Tags: javascript, networking, dns, subdomain, vercel

I'm working on a site that allows sellers to sell digital products online. I want to be able to do something similar to substack, where a writer can create their own subdomain immediately after account creation (ie. https://emilyoster.substack.com/).

So for instance my main domain is https://flurly.com. But let's say a seller named GoldenGooses signs up. I want to immediately after sign up, create a subdomain for https://golden-gooses.flurly.com. I have no idea how substack does this at scale and immediately since DNS records typically takes 24hrs+ to update for me.

Does anyone know how they do this voodoo magic?

Currently my project is written in Node and hosted on Vercel. I bought my domain and manage it with google domains.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into "wildcard records". Vercel, for example, sets a `CNAME` record for all subdomains automatically if you are using their Nameservers.

If you want to host all subdomains of your site on Vercel, you should switch to their Nameservers so you can have SSL certificates for all those subdomains.

Check https://vercel.com/blog/wildcard-domains and https://github.com/leerob/nextjs-multiple-domains